# Effects of many small Django apps vs. single large Django app on scalability?

Tags: python, django, optimization, scalability, scaling

I am using Django 1.6. I realize that Django best practices would be to decompose the functionality of my project into multiple "apps" so as to be more re-usable. I am wondering though - for the sake of *scalability* - would it be better to place all of my project's functionality into a single "app"? In this scenario, assume the total functionality of the project would be exactly the same in either case.

Any insights?

Comment: That depends on what each app would do, right? What matters for scale is where computations take place and which resources they need.

Comment: I am wondering primarily about how much "overhead" is added by there being multiple "models.py", "views.py", "urls.py", etc. files. It seems total processing time for serving the site might be reduced by consolidating all the code into a single app so only one of each of these files is present. But I might be wrong - it might actually require more processing since the file is larger...

Comment: Performance difference is minor, the real issue is about code management. Consider schema migration, tests organization etc.

Comment: What @shuo said is right.  computers are fast. People are slow. Unless you have some terribly inefficient code, you should place more emphasis on readability, pluggability, and maintainability. Man hours are much more expensive than computers. You can always just throw more processing power at a problem until a better fix is found, but poorly structured software can cause days or weeks of chaos, sometimes even longer